# Inserting a value into a text field from another text field which is ajax enabled jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 text fields. I need to fill the value from the first text field into the second text field.

I managed to do this with the below code but the problem is that it does not work perfectly as I think I am using the keyup function.

What I mean is the second text field gets the value if a type in the value in the first text field but if I select a listing in the first text field as this is ajax enabled it does not work. Below is my code.

```
$('#edit-nodequeid').keyup(function() {

    val = $('#edit-nodequeid').val();

    $('#edit-container-name').val(val);
});
```

Below is a screen shot

http://imagebin.org/202888

pls help,
vishal

Comment: where is your autocomplete code? need to use events within autocomplete to update value

Comment: Here is the link to to auto complete code http://pastebin.com/fxzcCYer. The framework drupal handles that hence I did not paste it here as its too long and generic

Comment: not interested in reading the whole plugin code...provide API link, should outline the events and options to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "ajax enabled", and the browsers auto complete/fill is not ajax?

It it is Ajax you can delegate the handler:

```
$(document).('keyup', '#edit-nodequeid', function() {
    val = $('#edit-nodequeid').val();
    $('#edit-container-name').val(val);
});
```

If the problem really is that the keyup event is not fired because no keys are pressed when selecting an autofill value, then just use another event, or multiple events, like so:

```
$('#edit-nodequeid').on('keyup paste change click whatever', function() {
    $('#edit-container-name').val(this.value);
});
```